# could not convert string to float from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

why cant i convert this to float

```
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].replace({'zero': '0', }, regex=True)
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].replace({"mm": ""}, regex=True)
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].replace({" ": ""}, regex=True)
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].str.strip().astype(float)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

i already tried to delete the space manually, still error

Comment: You should share a sample of the dataframe. It is otherwise hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that the string '0' is not the same as the numeric 0. The empty string '' can not be converted into a float. I suggest you look into the fillna() function for pandas as a quick way to convert all of the empty strings to nulls, and perhaps also use the pandas .map() function to convert the '0' strings to floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of conversion and there are empty or non-numeric values in the 'rain_1h' column of your DataFrame that cannot be converted to float. To handle this issue, you can perform the following steps:

Replace any non-numeric values (e.g., 'zero', 'mm', and other non-numeric characters) with an empty string.
Replace any remaining empty strings with NaN (Not-a-Number).
Convert the column to float.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample
data = {'rain_1h': ['1.2 mm', 'zero', '3.4 mm', '']}
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace non-numeric characters with an empty string
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].replace({'[^0-9.]': ''}, regex=True)

# Replace remaining empty strings with NaN
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].replace({'': np.nan})

# Convert the column to float
df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].astype(float)

print(df_tmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert an empty string (`''`) to a float, as written in the error message.
You have to convert this empty string to a float-like value beforehand: `df_tmp['rain_1h'] = df_tmp['rain_1h'].replace('', '0').astype(float)` for instance.